# Calling UIImagePickerController provides black screen

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to get photo from gallery for sending it to api. When I call `AttachNewFileClick()`, black screen appears.

```
@IBAction func AttachNewFileClick(_ sender: Any) {
    if checkPhotoAccess()==true {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController(rootViewController: self)
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func checkPhotoAccess() -> Bool {
    let status:PHAuthorizationStatus = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus();
    switch status {
    case PHAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined:
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({status in
            return
        })
        return checkPhotoAccess()
    case .denied:
        return false
    case .restricted:
        let permissionRequestAlert:UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Доступ к галлерее заблокирован", message: "Приложение не может получить доступ к вашей галлерее для прикрепления фото. Вероятно ранее вы заблокировали эту возможность", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Отмена", otherButtonTitles: "Открыть настройки")
        permissionRequestAlert.tag = PERMISSION_REQUEST_ALERT_TAG
        permissionRequestAlert.show()
        return false
    case .authorized:
        return true
    }
}
```

Then I added breakpoint to all exception and got this piece of code highlighted before exception being thrown

> libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw:
>   ->  0x1159b0f11 <+0>:   pushq  %rbp

and exception in log:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:]: key cannot be nil'

I run app in simulator iPhone SE (11.2 Xcode 9.2). Project min iOS version is 8.2. `UIImagePickerController` is called in `NavigationViewController` that was showed modally.

How this problem can be solved?

Comment: Your checkPhotoAccess makes no sense. You cannot return a result because requesting authorization  is asynchronous. And then on top of that you recourse infinitely, causing a stack overflow.

Comment: Your `UIImagePickerController` code works fine. There isn't any issue with it. I tested it with Xcode 9.3 beta simulator

Comment: @Krunal, xcode doesnt show me what line crash. It show me  this one: "libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw: -> 0x1159b0f11 <+0>: pushq %rbp" Now I am testing wighout check permission function (granted permission manually) and it still crashes

Comment: @Krunal, I did, exception creates after `preset(...)`

Comment: I created small demo project with only this functionality that crashes https://www.dropbox.com/s/oykl2wv13bfzw7h/playground.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are crashing is this line:

```
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController(rootViewController: self)
```

That is not how you create a UIImagePickerController. Just create it! It already has a root view controller of its own; do not attempt to change it. Just say:

```
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
```

---

Also, your `checkPhotoAccess` code is fatally flawed:

```
func checkPhotoAccess() -> Bool {
    let status:PHAuthorizationStatus = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus();
    switch status {
    case PHAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined:
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({status in
            return
        })
        return checkPhotoAccess()
    case .denied:
        return false
    case .restricted:
        let permissionRequestAlert:UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Доступ к галлерее заблокирован", message: "Приложение не может получить доступ к вашей галлерее для прикрепления фото. Вероятно ранее вы заблокировали эту возможность", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Отмена", otherButtonTitles: "Открыть настройки")
        permissionRequestAlert.tag = PERMISSION_REQUEST_ALERT_TAG
        permissionRequestAlert.show()
        return false
    case .authorized:
        return true
    }
}
```

To see why, let's eliminate everything except the `notDetermined` case:

```
func checkPhotoAccess() -> Bool {
    PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({status in
        return
    })
    return checkPhotoAccess()
}
```

Now think about the *order* in which those lines will execute. `requestAuthorization` is *asynchronous*. Therefore the order of execution is like this:

```
func checkPhotoAccess() -> Bool {
    PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({status in
        return // 2
    })
    return checkPhotoAccess() // 1
}
```

Okay, but then `2` will *never* execute, because `1` returns first. So we are left with this:

```
func checkPhotoAccess() -> Bool {
    return checkPhotoAccess()
}
```

But that is clearly insane. We have an infinite recursion.

The takeaway is that you *cannot* return a value from `checkPhotoAccess`, because you need to call `requestAuthorization` which is asynchronous. The correct way to implement this sort of thing is either to return `false` in the `.notDetermined` case, or else (better) to write a `checkPhotoAccess` method that receives a *completion function* and that can then *call* that function if it discovers that we have authorization.

---

Also you need to stop using UIAlertView immediately and convert to UIAlertController. UIAlertView was deprecated *long* ago. The compiler is warning you about this, so listen to what it's telling you!

Comment: For an example, see https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch17p697pickaMovieOrPhoto/ch30p960pickaMovie/ViewController.swift and look at the `checkForPhotoLibraryAccess(andThen:)` method and how it is used.

Comment: matt, thank you for reply. I understood this problem when you pointed on this in comments :) Actually I created demo, where i removed recursive call and it still crashes and I don't know why (link to dropbox with demo above)

Comment: Also did you notice that your code gets warnings for using UIAlertView? That means _don't use it_.

Comment: Okay, I see the problem: it's this line: `UIImagePickerController(rootViewController: self)` That's illegal. I've added that to the start of my answer... So you get two answers for the price of one!